# How to get my networked drives to also work on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, windows, vpn, active-directory

I have a networked drive on the XP side of my MacBook. I use a VPN and then can login to the drive. Nothing too special going on. I believe the server uses Active Directory.

There isn't a ton of info I have to enter. The `\\server.local.blah` blah
and some IP info.

I have never been able to get these to mount or show up and authenticate on the Mac side. I can use the network connect to login to the VPN, but directory access has always been a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the VPN is working and the same as on the Windows side, you should be able to enter the server details in the **Go > Connect to Server** (⌘K) dialog in Finder. If it's a standard Windows file share, just enter in `smb://server.local.blah` and it should connect.

However if that doesn't work, you'll need to provide more details on how your VPN and servers are set up.

Comment: Worked like a charm!